# DFP SafeFrame doesn't expand in MS Edge 41

Tags: javascript, iframe, microsoft-edge, double-click-advertising

Exactly as the title says: my code expands a SafeFrame to fill the window when clicked, using `$sf.ext.expand($sf.ext.geom().exp);`. The base ad-unit renders without issue, but the attempt to expand fails every time.

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, on desktop and mobile, and was working in Edge version 40 - but not the latest version (41.16299.15.0).

The issue seems to be limited to Google's SafeFrame implementation.

The tester at http://safeframes.net/examples/creative_test.html (which, as far as I can tell, uses the IAB reference implementation) works just fine in every browser I can find...

...whereas http://publisherconsole.appspot.com/safeframe/creative-preview.html, which uses GPT, exhibits the same behaviour (works everywhere but Edge 41).

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

UPDATE: As of 2018-02-22, GPT SafeFrames expand correctly in Edge 41, as everywhere else. As there hasn't been an Edge update, Google have presumably silently fixed the issue on their end.